# I want to get data from web site with Excel vba but I can't

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

```
Sub Galoplar()
    Sheets("Galop").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Dim elem As Object, trow As Object
    Dim R&, C&, S$
    With New XMLHTTP60
        .Open "POST", "https://yenibeygir.com/at/getatdetaytab", False
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .send "tab=galopTab&id=15673"
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S

        For Each elem In .getElementsByClassName("at_Galoplar")(0).Rows
            For Each trow In elem.Cells
                C = C + 1: Cells(R + 1, C) = trow.innerText
            Next trow
            C = 0: R = R + 1
        Next elem
    End With
End Sub
```

I get "Galopları" from the "[Web address](https://yenibeygir.com/at/15673/budakhan)" link with the above code. But I can't get "Yarışları" data with the following code.

```
Sub Yarislar()
    Sheets("Yaris").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Dim elem As Object, trow As Object
    Dim R&, C&, S$

    With New XMLHTTP60
        .Open "POST", "https://yenibeygir.com/at/getatdetaytab", False
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .send "tab=yarisTab&id=15673"
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S

        For Each elem In .getElementsByClassName("at_Yarislar")(0).Rows
            For Each trow In elem.Cells
                C = C + 1: Cells(R + 1, C) = trow.innerText
            Next trow
            C = 0: R = R + 1
        Next elem
    End With
End Sub
```

My question is about, where am I making a mistake?

How do I use a vba code to get the "Son 1 Yıl" data on the "[Web address](https://yenibeygir.com/jokey/10294/mehmet-kaya)" link?

Comment: Please limit to one question at a time.  _How do I use a vba code to get the "Son 1 Yıl" data on the "Web address" link?_ is a new question and should be posted as such.

Comment: Okay, but I have no right to ask new questions.

Comment: Is the site saying you cannot ask a new question?

Comment: You have reached your question limit
It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon! 

You've asked 3 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely.

Comment: It's been 0 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 5 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments.

Comment: This is the way the site warns.

Comment: Ah that explains it. I suspect you have been deleting poorly received questions. This once I will add in the second bit of info but please be aware that, as you have discovered from my comments, asking two questions at the same time is not the way SO tends to work in terms of eliciting quality answers that are of use to future users.

Comment: You're right. I erased the questions I couldn't ask. Inexperience and bad english. sorry.

Comment: You forgot to mention about the first working script which you've got from ***[this blog](https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/receiving-data-from-a-website-with-excel-vba.39824/)*** @Cumhur Ay.

Comment: You're right, SIM. The first code (galoplar) was written by SHAHIN, a member of chandoo.org. And I would like to thank him. He's a very talented programmer. But I had to look for other answers because my codes were half-finished. I'm sorry I didn't mention him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial landing tab does not have jquery initiated XHR events which the other tabs do.

You can issue a GET request against your landing page to grab the table by its class name for the first tab.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Yarislar()
    Dim s As String, html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    With New XMLHTTP60
        .Open "GET", "https://yenibeygir.com/at/15673/budakhan", False
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .send
        s = .responseText
    End With

    Dim hTable As HTMLTable, clipboard As Object
    html.body.innerHTML = s
    Set hTable = html.querySelector(".at_Yarislar")

    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
    clipboard.PutInClipboard
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

---

For your second question (as you are unable to post it):

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim s As String, html As HTMLDocument, hTable As Long, hTables As Object, clipboard As Object, ws As Object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With New XMLHTTP60
        .Open "POST", "https://yenibeygir.com/jokey/updatestats", False
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .send "id=10294&LastYear=True"
        s = .responseText
    End With

    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    html.body.innerHTML = s
    Set hTables = html.querySelectorAll(".Stats")

    For hTable = 0 To hTables.Length - 1
        Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        clipboard.SetText hTables.item(hTable).outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 2, 1).PasteSpecial
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

---

Edit: There now seems to be problems with late bound clipboard reference in some cases. Here is generic early bound method where hTable is the target HTMLTable object.

For clipboard early bound go VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft-Forms 2.0 Object Library.

If you add a UserForm to your project, the library will get automatically added.

```
Dim clipboard As DataObject
Set clipboard = New DataObject
clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
clipboard.PutInClipboard
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
```

Comment: Super. The code is working. I'm grateful. One last question; How do I use a vba code to get the "Son 1 Yıl" data on the "https://yenibeygir.com/jokey/10294/mehmet-kaya" link?

Comment: The first question I had in this question was already. I feel like I'm asking two questions, but I'm sorry. I can't read all the rules because I don't have enough English. This translation is from google translate.

Comment: I have answered _But I can't get "Yarışları" data with the following code. where am I making a mistake?_ That is your first question.

Comment: Your new question should be  _How do I use a vba code to get the "Son 1 Yıl"  ?_

Comment: First Question; I get "Galopları" from the "Web address" link with the above code. But I can't get "Yarışları" data with the following code.
Code...
My question is about, where am I making a mistake?

Second Question; How do I use a vba code to get the "Son 1 Yıl" data on the "Web address" link?

Comment: Yes. And on StackOverflow you should limit each post to one question. _Second Question; How do I use a vba code to get the "Son 1 Yıl" data on the "Web address" link_ should be posted as a new question.

Comment: I have excel vba knowledge to do my job. But this is a pretty weak level. The codes for my hobbies are quite strong. And I can't make it. Thank you for your support.

Comment: "Public Sub Yarislar" The code crashes when I run inside the loop. The code doesn't work when I change the "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908005/why-doesnt-the-code-receive-data-from-the-web-page" code you typed. Where do I make a mistake?