# How do I clean up objects in Excel vba?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

```
Public Sub D_Galoplar()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Asay(1 To 250)
    Dim Jsay(1 To 100)
    For q = 2 To Sheets("Y").Columns("A:A").Find(What:="boş").Row - 1
        Asay(q - 1) = Sheets("Y").Range("A" & q)
    Next q
    For q = 2 To Sheets("Y").Columns("C:C").Find(What:="boş").Row - 1
        Jsay(q - 1) = Sheets("Y").Range("C" & q)
    Next q
For w = 1 To 250
    Cells.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
    If Asay(w) < 1 Then Exit For

    Dim elem As Object, trow As Object
    Dim R&, C&, s$
    With New XMLHTTP60
        .Open "POST", "https://yenibeygir.com/at/getatdetaytab", False
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .send "tab=galopTab&id=" & Asay(w)
        s = .responseText
    End With
    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = s
        For Each elem In .getElementsByClassName("at_Galoplar")(0).Rows
            For Each trow In elem.Cells
                C = C + 1: Cells(R + 1, C) = trow.innerText
            Next trow
            C = 0: R = R + 1
        Next elem
    End With

    Cells.UnMerge
    Range("A1").Select

    If Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row < 2 Then GoTo ATLA2

    Columns("A:A").Insert
    For i = 2 To Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row - 1
        Range("A" & i) = Asay(w)
    Next i

    Range("O2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-9]),""-"",IF(ISNUMBER(RC[-9]),RC[-9]/4,((LEFT(RC[-9],1)*6000)+(MID(RC[-9],3,2)*100)+(RIGHT(RC[-9],1)*10))/400))"
    Range("P2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-9]),""-"",IF(ISNUMBER(RC[-9]),RC[-9]/6,((LEFT(RC[-9],1)*6000)+(MID(RC[-9],3,2)*100)+(RIGHT(RC[-9],1)*10))/600))"
    Range("Q2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-9]),""-"",IF(ISNUMBER(RC[-9]),RC[-9]/8,((LEFT(RC[-9],1)*6000)+(MID(RC[-9],3,2)*100)+(RIGHT(RC[-9],1)*10))/800))"
    Range("R2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-9]),""-"",IF(ISNUMBER(RC[-9]),RC[-9]/10,((LEFT(RC[-9],1)*6000)+(MID(RC[-9],3,2)*100)+(RIGHT(RC[-9],1)*10))/1000))"
    Range("S2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-9]),""-"",IF(ISNUMBER(RC[-9]),RC[-9]/12,((LEFT(RC[-9],1)*6000)+(MID(RC[-9],3,2)*100)+(RIGHT(RC[-9],1)*10))/1200))"
    Range("T2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-9]),""-"",IF(ISNUMBER(RC[-9]),RC[-9]/14,((LEFT(RC[-9],1)*6000)+(MID(RC[-9],3,2)*100)+(RIGHT(RC[-9],1)*10))/1400))"
    Range("O2:T2").Copy
    Range("O2:O" & Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    Cells.Copy
    Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Columns("O:T").Cut Columns("F:K")

    Range("A2:N" & Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    Sheets("Galop").Range("A" & Sheets("Galop").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ATLA2:
    Cells.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Next w
End Sub
```

I want to get a lot of data with the `For Next` cycle, but after a while the page hangs. How can I reset objects at the end of each cycle?

Asay numbers
10182
10221
10279
10303
10316
10325
10360
10370
10680
11598
11629
11715
11745
12335
12385
12533
12559
13154
13393
13635
13641
13669
13673
14027
14057
14062
14228
14619
14674
14687
14743
14770
14778
15197
15217
15323
15382
15507
15775
15828
16077
16335
16510
17149
17513
17867
18532
37964
60176
66067
66255
66581
66582
66896
66998
67056
67309
67356
67379
67473
68008
68012
68162
68298
68312
68320
68332
68333
68353
68383
68545
68702
68775
68922
69445
69606
69817
69963
69968
69985
69986
70048
70202
71372
(boş)

Comment: I think it is an XY problem (see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Can you instead explain what your actual goal is? Probably there is another approach where you don't run into that issue at all.

Comment: To analyze, I want to get the works data of 70-80 horses.

Comment: Again, why are you doing any of this? Excel [can pull data from web pages](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-a-web-page-power-query-b2725d67-c9e8-43e6-a590-c0a175bd64d8) for at least a decade now. PowerQuery can clean, transform data quite easily, plus it can read from a *lot* of sources, not just web sites. Finally, you don't need to *paste* just to set a cell's or range's values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slowing down maybe due to throttling of network if you are trying to hit the site too many times in quick succession. This is particularly likely given your access method. Better would be to see if an API is available to bulk access info. You are likely going through many networks to get to this page as well. It may be possible to get some basic info about delays from [TRACERT](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-tell-if-certain-websites-are-being-throttled-by-my-ISP) command from a command prompt.

You are doing a POST so remember there is a fair amount of server side stuff going on as well.

You don't need to set `elem` to `Nothing` as it only exists during your `For Loop`. Same for `tRow`.

Putting `.getElementsByClassName("at_Galoplar")(0).Rows` into a variable will provided faster referencing.

Write the results to an array first and then dump the array out to the sheet in one go will provide significant improvement in speed.

Using `New` keyword can lead to unexpected behaviour. You can create one instance of `HTMLDocument` and work with that provided you have good error handling in. I have had occassional cases in a loop where I have had to set `HTMLDocument` to `Nothing` before looping back round.

---

Personally, I would *cheat* and re-write this to leverage that you can issue GET requests to get the same info. I use a class to hold the XMLHTTP object, and an array to hold the results. I write the results out in one go. This takes a few seconds to run for me. The asay numbers are in `Sheet1` range `A1:A84`.

Class module clsHTTP

```
Option Explicit    
Private http As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim sResponse As String
    With http
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        GetString = sResponse
    End With
End Function
```

Standard module 1

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DGaloplar()
    Dim asays(), ws As Worksheet, asay As Long, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim http As clsHTTP, url As String, headers(), numberOfRequests As Long

    headers = Array("Asay", "Tarih", "Sehir", "Kg", "Jokey", "400", "600", "800", "1000", "1200", "1400", "Ç", "Pist", "Durum")
    Set http = New clsHTTP
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    asays = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:A84").Value) 'Load asay values from sheet 1

    Const numTableRows As Long = 11
    Const numTableColumns As Long = 15
    Const BASE_URL As String = "https://yenibeygir.com/at/getatdetaytab/?tab=galopTab&id="

    numberOfRequests = UBound(asays)

    Dim results(), headerRow As Boolean, tRows As Object, tRow As Object, iRow As Long
    Dim tCells As Object, tCell As Object, r As Long, c As Long, hTable As HTMLTable
    ReDim results(1 To numTableRows * numberOfRequests, 1 To numTableColumns)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For asay = 1 To numberOfRequests
        headerRow = True
        url = BASE_URL & asays(asay)
        html.body.innerHTML = http.GetString(url)
        Set hTable = html.querySelector(".at_Galoplar")
        Set tRows = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")

        For Each tRow In tRows
            If Not headerRow Then
                c = 2: r = r + 1
                results(r, 1) = asays(asay)
                Set tCells = tRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                For Each tCell In tCells
                    results(r, c) = tCell.innerText
                    c = c + 1
                Next
            End If
            headerRow = False
        Next
    Next

    With ws
        .Cells(1, 3).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 3).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**Refereces:**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: yes I think it is due to fast and frequent data demand. For example, 1 to 20 is not a problem.

Comment: How can I include all data into an array by including Asay (w)?

Comment: You presumably know how many columns are retrieved (unless this varies?) so you could oversize an array row wise with the appropriate number of columns and write to that (using a rowCounter variable to keep track of how many rows you have populated). Transpose and ReDim the rows to the right size using rowCounter variable. Or ignore the resize and dump the whole thing out - you'll have some empty rows at the end but doesn't matter if not overwriting anything.

Comment: Sorumu değiştirdim. Kodun tamamını yazdım. Y sayfasındaki pivottable'dan okuduğu numaraları da yazdım. Bu şekliyle kod çalışırken bir süre sonra kilitleniyor.

Comment: The code you typed for "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766563/i-want-to-get-data-from-web-site-with-excel-vba-but-i-cant" question works very well for this question. Thanks to your codes, I learned to get data with the "get" method. but the "post" job is a bit distressed.

Comment: Without working with your dataset all I can say is immediately clear is that you want to avoid touching the worksheet as much as you do. Read data in from the sheet once, into an array. Loop the array. Write results to an array. Write the array to the sheet. Each time you use .Select, .Cells etc you are gaining overhead and slowing your process.

Comment: You know how much beginner I am from the code. I've also reviewed the codes you've written, but I don't understand how to loop through, write data into a table, and export it to excel.

Comment: I have written an update. Let me know. It runs in a few seconds.

Comment: Perfect master. I bow in front of you with respect. Thank you so much.

Comment: I made little changes to the code. On the line "html.body.innerHTML = http.GetString (url)" gives error 7. what would be the reason?

Comment: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("X")
    Set ww = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Y")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Asays = Application.Transpose(ww.Range("A1:A" & ww.Columns("A:A").Find(What:="boş").Row - 1).Value)

Comment: I don't know. If you run my code as it was before you changed does it sitll run fine?

Comment: I'm sorry the error is caused by me. Asay numbers start from A2, not A1. I've fixed it working super.

Answer (score 4):

In general `Set elem = Nothing` is what you need.

In your code you are assigning the variables within a for-each loop, thus even if you set them to `Nothing` later, there would not be a performance bonus.

Comment: `For Each elem`, `For Each trow` is no assigning? Probably you missed them ;) • But I doubt setting them `nothing` will solve the issue.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ -  yes, there is assignment, but still the performance bonus is discussable. The `Set elem = Nothing` breaks a reference, should not be doing something more.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting those object to `Nothing`, like below:

```
Set elem = Nothing
Set trow = Nothing
```

I am not sure whether you need variable declarations in your loop, you can take them out of the loop, this might save some time.

But I think your HTTP requests are taking so long, not any VBA code.

**UPDATE**

Try setting `Application.EnableEvents` and `Application.ScreenUpdating` to `False` at the beggining of macro and setting them back to `True` at the end.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't. Every round of the cycle, the Excel page where the macro copied the data fills down. It hangs after a while.

Comment: @CumhurAy - I also think that the HTTP requests are the time problem. Try with `For w = 1 To 2` to see whether there is a difference.

Comment: for example no problem up to 20

Comment: @CumhurAy See additional suggestions.