# Why doesn't the code receive data from the web page?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

```
Sub Yarislar()
    Dim Asays(), ws As Worksheet, Asay As Long, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim http As clsHTTP, url As String, headers(), numberOfRequests As Long
    headers = Array("Asay", "Tarih", "Sehir", "Cins", "Grup", "Msf/Pist", "Derece", "Sira", "Jokey", "Kilo", "GC", "Hnd", "Gny", "Taki")
    Set http = New clsHTTP
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("X")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Asays = Application.Transpose(Sheets("Y").Range("A2:A" & Sheets("Y").Columns("A:A").Find(What:="boş").Row - 1).Value)
    Const numTableRows As Long = 11
    Const numTableColumns As Long = 15
    Const BASE_URL As String = "https://yenibeygir.com/at/"
    numberOfRequests = UBound(Asays)
    Dim results(), headerRow As Boolean, tRows As Object, tRow As Object, iRow As Long
    Dim tCells As Object, tCell As Object, r As Long, c As Long, hTable As HTMLTable
    ReDim results(1 To numTableRows * numberOfRequests, 1 To numTableColumns)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Asay = 1 To numberOfRequests
        headerRow = True
        url = BASE_URL & Asays(Asay)
        html.body.innerHTML = http.GetString(url)
        Set hTable = html.querySelector(".at_Yarislar")
        Set tRows = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each tRow In tRows
            If Not headerRow Then
                c = 2: r = r + 1
                results(r, 1) = Asays(Asay)
                Set tCells = tRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                For Each tCell In tCells
                    results(r, c) = tCell.innerText
                    c = c + 1
                Next
            End If
            headerRow = False
        Next
    Next
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
end sub
```

Why is the code I modified @Qharr not working to retrieve other data from the same web page? The code that @QHarr wrote for the "Galoplar" data works perfectly, but when I modify the same code, it doesn't work for "Yarislar". Do I make a mistake in table selection?

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854186/how-do-i-clean-up-objects-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Doesn't work is the most liked error description;( What is the difference on the site to the workin gexample? BaseURL is very short, comared to Galoptar.If Iuse the concated url in a browser (https://yenibeygir.com/at/Asay) I get redirected to https://yenibeygir.com/at/. Seems something is missing in the url.

Comment: Asay for next cycle to be counted. For example, 12543, 14362, 11563 and the like. It will read these values with the code Sheets("Y").Range("A2:A" & Sheets("Y").Columns("A:A").Find(What:="boş").Row - 1. In the "Y" sheet.

Comment: Sorry I read Array for asay. Provide sample Url and check your created urls with `Debug.Print url ` put this after `url = BASE_URL & Asays(Asay)`

Comment: ^^ As per provided comments by @ComputerVersteher. Where are some sample ids /full URLs? Parts ofthe original URL base are missing and so is the class definition. When you manually type one of these full URLs into a browser does it retrieve data? And what happens if "boş" is not found?

Comment: error in line "results(r, 1) = Asays(Asay)". error 9

Comment: "https://yenibeygir.com/at/67382" this url comes with the data I want.

Comment: The site has different tables structure (e.g. just 12 cols) adapt the headers array to the new headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the class definition. You also, I think, need a different URL construction. You haven't provided ones but based on your prior questions, and with a little imagination, you need to add a URL construction of:

```
BASE_URL & asay & /name
```

e.g.

https://yenibeygir.com/at/10221/dorukhatun

So, column A in source sheet must have the names to go with the asay ids i.e. must contain strings such as `10221/dorukhatun`.

You must then also adjust the constants governing row numbers and column numbers in tables.

You will need to adjust the source column A ranges appropriately.

I used the two ids I could remember and had the following in A1:A2 (note some results are now present in sheet as have test run)

Sheet1:

[image]

**VBA:**

Class clsHTTP:

```
Option Explicit
Private http As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim sResponse As String
    With http
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        GetString = sResponse
    End With
End Function
```

Standard module 1:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DYarislar()
    Dim asays(), ws As Worksheet, asay As Long, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim http As clsHTTP, url As String, headers(), numberOfRequests As Long

    headers = Array("Asay", "Tarih", "Sehir", "K.Cinsi", "Gr", "Msf/Pist", "Derece", "S", "Jokey", "Kilo", "G.Ç", "Hnd", "Gny", "Taki")
    Set http = New clsHTTP
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    asays = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:A2").Value) 'Load asay values from sheet 1

    Const numTableRows As Long = 44
    Const numTableColumns As Long = 14
    Const BASE_URL As String = "https://yenibeygir.com/at/"

    numberOfRequests = UBound(asays)

    Dim results(), headerRow As Boolean, tRows As Object, tRow As Object, iRow As Long
    Dim tCells As Object, tCell As Object, r As Long, c As Long, hTable As HTMLTable
    ReDim results(1 To numTableRows * numberOfRequests, 1 To numTableColumns)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For asay = 1 To numberOfRequests
        headerRow = True
        url = BASE_URL & asays(asay)
        html.body.innerHTML = http.GetString(url)

        Set hTable = html.querySelector(".at_Yarislar")

        Set tRows = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")

        For Each tRow In tRows
            If Not headerRow Then
                c = 2: r = r + 1
                results(r, 1) = asays(asay)
                Set tCells = tRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                For Each tCell In tCells
                    results(r, c) = tCell.innerText
                    c = c + 1
                Next
            End If
            headerRow = False
        Next
    Next

    With ws
        .Cells(1, 3).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 3).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Again a very successful study. You know this. I hope that I can decode the data from the web through these codes. Thank you so much. I appreciate it.

Comment: Why can't I see the picture?

Comment: I don't know. I will paste another link here.

Comment: A last question, taking refuge in your forgiveness; how do you see that the web table has 44 rows?

Comment: I saw the picture. Thanks.

Comment: I am oversizing to account for different numbers of result rows e.g. https://yenibeygir.com/at/10221/dorukhatun 29 rows

https://yenibeygir.com/at/69963/hesperos  6 rows. Pick a number greater than the likely largest number of results on any given page.

Comment: Some horses may have more than 100 races. Then wouldn't this code work?

Comment: Change the Const numTableRows As Long = 44 to a large number e.g. 150.

Comment: I understand very well. But I want to close the subject with a question that I hope will be the last. Let's say there are 100, 20, 30 etc. horses that have races and I want to get only the first 20 of them. Then Should I change the code? (google translate)

Comment: Thank you for your interest and effort. Good evening.

Comment: Me again :). How do I get data with links?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182214/discussion-between-qharr-and-cumhur-ay).

Comment: Like "xlWebFormattingAll"